# Каким образом можно реализовать безопасность в приложении

Tags: java, android, безопасность

Есть приложения в которое нужно войти логин\пасс и есть сервер который при успешном логине возвращает токен который действительный N часов.

Как реализовать безопасную передачу данных на сервер и получения с сервера что бы предоврать перехват паролей или взлом приложения.

Для работы с сетью используеться retrofit 2.

Кто как реализовывал безопасность в своих приложених или где то читал про это?

Comment: у сервера должен быть функционал рефреша токена.
если есть возможность не хранить пароль, то постарайтесь так и делать
Как бы вы не шифровали его, и где бы не хранили всё равно есть вероятность взлома.
а несанкционированный доступ к серверу это куда более благоприятная ситуация, чем угон пароля, который является личными данными юзера.

Comment: @SviatVolkov если вытянут пароль юзера это не проблема так как в юзеров ограниченные права. Больше безпокоинт несанкционированный доступ к серверу. Ссылку на которую обращаеться приложение можно  спрятать с помощью gradle в BuildConfig  и в приложении использовать как BuildConfig.url это будет безопасно или же ссылку все равно можно получить?

Comment: билд конфиг это обычный джава класс у вас в проекте)

Comment: @SviatVolkov 
я имею ввиду в Gradle файл добавить  buildConfigField('String' , 'url', "myLink")

Comment: и он сгенерируется в BuildConfig.java который лежит где-то в generated вашего модуля и будет так же всем доступен как и обычный код

Comment: @SviatVolkov ссылки спрятать вообще никак получаетсья ?

Comment: Нет, если вы хотите что-то на клиенте прятать - ничего не выйдет. Так что безопасностью сервера занимаются только бек енд разработчики. ваша задача как андроид разработчика - хранить поменьше данных юзера

Answer (score 2):

Пароли в чистом виде лучше не хранить, а хэшировать их с помощью хэшфункций, например функциии MD5(MD2, MD3 и т.д), но есть и другие, как более эффективные так и менее. Суть хэширования заключается в том, чтобы последовательность символов неопределенной длинны преобразовать в последовательность чисел определенной(ХЭШ), причем результат хэширования для разного слова будет всегда уникальным(За исключением коллизий, но они бывают очень редкими, и подобрать их сложно, но можно). При этом ХЭШ перевести обратно в исходное слово нельзя. Также желательно хранить пароли отдельно от общей информации. Таким образом, пароли в чистом виде не хранятся, их знают только владельцы аккаунтов и мошенник заполучивший доступ к информации о паролях получит только набор ХЭШей, с которым ни чего сделать не сможет

Можно передать в хэшфункцию, например, книгу из тысячи страниц и получить на выходе строчку длинной , например, 16 символов, но изменив в книги хоть один символ вы получите на выходе совершенно другую последовательность. Как я уже говорил, бывают и коллизии вы можете передать две абсолютно разные последовательности(например, справочник из 1000 страниц и одно слово) и получить на выходе одинаковый результат, но это бывает очень редко и таких совпадений насчитано единицы на миллионы комбинаций.

Comment: хэширование практически не защищает пароль. Если злоумышленник утянет значение хэша, то брутфорсом он справится с вашим паролем очень даже быстро..

Comment: Во первых, ХЭШ ни чего полезного из себя не представляет и вам не нужно его красть, чтобы попытаться подобрать пароль!

Во вторых, если пароль хороший, имеет большой алфавит и достаточную длину, то времени вам потребуется много. Допустим, если вы используете метод полного перебора, то хороший пароль вам придется подбирать годами. Если же в вашем арсенале более  оптимальные методы перебора, то времени потребуется в разы меньше, но все же, это может занять десятки дней или недель.

Comment: В третьих, вам понадобится пара: логин, пароль.
В четвертых, попыток входа в аккаунт ограничено (Если разработчик постарался)

Comment: @Юрий 3 попытки входа потом бан логина на 3 часа.
Интересует больше как спрятать ссылки на которые идет обращение. и защитить приложение на пример он декомпиляции.